# Animate b2Body with CCSprites?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I would like to animate my b2Body's in my game. Is it possible to use CCActions with them or does Box2D use a different way of animating things? Each b2Body I have is connected to a CCSprite and the CCSprite gets updated to the current position of the b2Body that corresponds to it. 
So anyway how could I animate a b2Body to move from position A to position B?

Any tips and advice would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my new code:

```
-(void)addBody
{

    boxImg=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ballImg1.png"];
    boxImg.position=ccp(30,100);
    [self addChild:boxImg];

    // Define the dynamic body.
    //Set up a 1m squared box in the physics world
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    bodyDef.position.Set(30.0/PTM_RATIO, 100.0/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = boxImg;
    body1= world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body1->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    posx1=300.0;
    posy1=100.0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveAni) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}
 -(void)moveAni
  {
 body1->SetTransform(b2Vec2(posx1/PTM_RATIO, posy1/PTM_RATIO), 0);
 id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO)];
[boxImg runAction:action];
  }
```

First u move the body manually using "SetTransform" ,and use this function

Comment: I am not quite sure how this works. You animate the CCSprite but in your game loop, you are setting the position of the CCSprite to the b2Body which is not being animated. Would you mind explaining a bit more how this works?

Comment: Ah ok so you are moving the b2Body and CCSprite in a animation. Since in my case all my CCSprites follow my b2Bodys, is there any reason to use CCMoveTo? Have you tried deleting that line?